# Obtener la opción con un select desde la base de datos en Django

Tags: html, django

Estoy haciendo un formulario de de alumnos que inscriben materias, quiero la opción de materia con un `select` que seleccione la materia desde la bd. Este es mi código:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Alumno

class DatosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alumno
        fields = [
            'id',
            'Nombre',
            'Apellido',
            'Email',
            'Sexo',
            'Materia',
        ]

        labels = {
            'id': 'id',
            'Nombre':'Nombre',
            'Apellido':'Apellido',
            'sexo':'sexo',
            'Materia':'Materia'

         }

        widgets = {
           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder elegir más de una materia con un `select` deberías tener una relación de ManyToMany entre los modelos Alumno y Materia.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que este es el modelo de Materia:

```
from django.db import models

class Materia(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Y este el de Alumno:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.materia.models import Materia

class Alumno(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    email = models.EmailField()
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    materias = models.ManyToManyField(Materia)
    edad = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre} {self.apellido}'
```

form.py

```
from .models import Alumno
from django.forms import ModelForm

class AlumnoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alumno
        fields = ['nombre', 'apellido', 'edad', 'genero', 'materias']
```

alumno_materias.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alumnos</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Enviar formulario</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import AlumnoForm

def alumno_materias(request):
    alumno_form = AlumnoForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        alumno_form = AlumnoForm(request.POST)
        if alumno_form.is_valid():
            alumno_form.save()
            return redirect('alumno')
        else:
            print(alumno_form.errors)
   return render(request, 'alumno_materias.html', {'form': alumno_form})
```